# adding the new row in the bottom of the uitableview after loading the web service value in the tableview in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i am very new to the objective c in my app the tableview is dynamically updated by the web service after loading the web service i have to create one new row and i have to add one new label in it how to do that.can anyone pls suggest me how to do that in my app..

This is my sample code

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    customcell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[customcell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.finacialyear.text=[self->entries1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.term.text=[self->entries2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.balance.text=[self->entries3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    return cell;
}
```

Here entries 1,entries 2,entries 3 are nsmutablearray that having the json values.

Comment: why don't return one more cell while retuning cell & then show use one label hide others label **or** second way you can use UITableViewCell Basic style.

Comment: @pavithra what you want in lastcell? means you need to display total balance in last cell?

Comment: @IOS_DEV yes i have to show the balance in last cell.

Comment: @Mukesh balance cell is having the list of balance amount i have to add all the values and have to display the final amount in last row.

Comment: @pavithra i think just add one view in bottom of tableview than add label in view,display balance

Comment: @IOS_DEV ya you are write but i need that in the bottom of the table view due to some of the reasons is that possible to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
// build the index paths for insertion
// since you're adding to the end of datasource, the new rows will start at count
NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
NSInteger currentCount = self.datasource.count;
for (int i = 0; i < dataToAdd.count; i++) {
    [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:currentCount+i inSection:0]];
}

// do the insertion
[self.dataSource addObjects:dataToAdd];

// tell the table view to update (at all of the inserted index paths)
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: @pavithra, Let me know if this helps for you.